# Python : How to use operator in all()?

Tags: python

I try to check all values from a dictionary with multiple criteria. With this code there is no probleme for check if all values are equal to 1 for exemple :

```
config = {"a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1, "d": 3, "e": 2}

if all(value == 1 for value in config.values()):
    print('correct')
else:
    print('wrong')
```

But now if want to add some operator in this code to check if all values are 1 Or 2 Or 3 for example results aren't working like i want :

```
config = {"a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1, "d": 3, "e": 5}

if all(value == (1 or 2 or 3) for value in config.values()):
    print('correct')
else:
    print('wrong')

>>>correct
```

I've also try many variations like :

```
if all(value == 1 or 2 or 3 for value in config.values()):
if all((value == 1 or 2 or 3) for value in config.values()):
if all(value for value in config.values() == 1 or 2 or 3):
...
```

So how to use correctly these operators to make this work please ?

Comment: Try `if all(value in [1, 2, 3] for value in config.values()):`, which is a bit shorter way of writing `if all((value == 1 or value == 2 or value == 3) for value in config.values()):`

Comment: You can do `all(value in [1,2,3] for value in config.values())`, but what you're really doing here is set math, so use sets: `{1, 2, 3}.issuperset(config.values())`.

Comment: Thank's this is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have inside `all` is a generator expression (which can be replaced with any iterable), so use it like one:

```
all(value in {1, 2, 3} for value in config.values())
```

---

`value == (1 or 2 or 3)` isn't working because it is being treated as:

```
value = 1
```

`1 or 2 or 3` will return 1<sup>*</sup>, so all the values are being compared for eqality with 1.

<sup>*</sup> An `or` chain will return the first *truthy* value or the last value in the chain as the default (irrespective of it's truthiness).

Comment: you might want to explain why `1 or 2 or 3` wasn't working since that seemed to be the main point of confusion